# Using SQL Sequence in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I'm trying to make a select word like this.

```
string cagri = "INSERT INTO TBL_IS VALUES ('tbl_is_sequence.nextval','" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "',' + Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList4.SelectedValue) + ','" + TextBox5.Text + "')";
```

When i trying it to the SQL Developement Tool, there is no problem. But when i trying it at c#
 it's a problem. It cannot add the values to the table.

> tbl_is_sequence is a sequence which auto-increase "id" value.
>   *tbl_is have 4 colons which is; ID(number),chapter_name(varchar),work_priority(number),description(varchar)

Comment: 'tbl_is_sequence.nextval' should not be enclosed in quotes

Comment: This whole thing screams SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the basic level, take the `nextval` part out of quotes. However, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE parameterize this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
INSERT INTO TBL_IS (ID,chapter_name,work_priority,description)
VALUES (tbl_is_sequence.nextval,:name,:pri,:desc)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pri", Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList4.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("desc", TextBox5.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(note, I'm not an Oracle person, and the above is from memory only - but *along those lines*)